# swagger is not rendering requestbody

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi, swagger-editor

I have the following openapi 3.0 compliant yaml file which I am trying to render via swagger. There are no errors reported in the yaml file, but the `requestBody` is not rendered on the swagger GUI. I just get a `parameters` field which is empty but nothing rendered for the request body, nor do I get any errors. Screenshot below.

```
paths:
  /my-api:
    post:
      summary: My API Summary
      description: My API Description
      tags:
        - Cost Center
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                data:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/ReqBodyStruct'
```

[image: Screnshot]

What is the way to get the RequestBody also shown in the swagger gui ? Do I miss something ?

Comment: Can your post the complete API definition, including the `ReqBodyStruct` schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to these two issues [OAS 3.0: Support for media type examples (aka request/response body examples) #3437](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3437) and [Examples are not showing #2651](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2651) from the Swagger UI github page this should be fixed in version `3.23.0` (of June 29, 2019).